# How to issue signal each time a row is edited in QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qlistwidget

```
class genericTaskList : public QListWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT  
    public:
        QListWidgetItem *defaultText;

        genericTaskList (QWidget *parentWidget)
        {
            setParent      (parentWidget);
            setFixedSize (445, 445);

            defaultText = new QListWidgetItem ("Double click here to compose the task");
            defaultText->setFlags (defaultText->flags () | Qt :: ItemIsEditable);

            insertItem     (0, defaultText);

            QObject :: connect (this, SIGNAL (currentRowChanged (int)), this, SLOT (addDefaultText (int)));
        }

    public slots:
        void addDefaultText (int rr)
        {
            std::cout << "\ndsklfjsdklfhsdklhfkjsdf\n";

            insertItem (++rr, defaultText);
        }
};
```

This code is supposed to issue a signal each time the row gets edited.

After I call "**insertItem**" in the constructor, the signal is issued.
But, that's it. It never gets issued after that - no matter how many times I edit the row.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentRowChanged` indicates the row *selection* has changed, not the content of the row. Perhaps you want to use `currentTextChanged` or `itemChanged` instead.

The reuse of the word *current* and *changed* in the QT docs is quite confusing.

Answer (score 4):

At first it seems like QListWidget::itemChanged is the way to go, but soon you run into a problem: the signal is sent for everything - inserts, removes, changing colors, checking boxes, etc!  So then you end up trying to put in flags and filter everywhere by intercepting various signals to find out if editing was the actual event. It gets very messy.

There is also QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged , which would seem like a good solution. It even has a parameter "const QVector& lstRoles" so you could scan for Qt::EditRole and see if it was really edited.  Alas, there's a catch - it gets called for everything just like QListWidget::itemChanged and unfortunately, for QListWidget anyway, the roles parameter is always empty when it's called (I tried it). So much for that idea...

Fortunately, there's still hope... This solution does the trick! :

http://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2013/11/qlistwidget-and-item-edit-event.html

He uses QAbstractItemDelegate::closeEditor, but I prefer using QAbstractItemDelegate::commitData.

So make a connect like so...

```
connect(ui.pLstItems->itemDelegate(), &QAbstractItemDelegate::commitData, this, &MyWidget::OnLstItemsCommitData);
```

Then implement the slot like this...

```
void MyWidget::OnLstItemsCommitData(QWidget* pLineEdit)
{
        QString strNewText = reinterpret_cast<QLineEdit*>(pLineEdit)->text();
    int nRow = ui.pLstItems->currentRow();
        // do whatever you need here....
}
```

Now you have a slot that gets called only when the list item's text has been edited!

Comment: Thanks very much.  For those doing this with Python here is the signal connect syntax:  myQListWidget.itemDelegate().commitData.connect(myslot)

Answer (score 1):

Warning: A QListWidgetItem can only be added to a QListWidget once. Adding the same QListWidgetItem multiple times to a QListWidget will result in undefined behavior.

So even if it will emit the signal I think you should better to add newly created Item.
And when do you want the new row to be inserted ? -
as soon as item is double clicked or finishing edit - they differ.